# Change in shape after adding mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers

I'm making a knife. I have added subsurf modifier to the mesh. After adding the mirror modifier, the shape of the knife changes. The order of the modifier stack is the mirror on top and subsurf below. Why does the shape change?. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

**Before adding mirror modifier**

[image]

**After adding mirror modifier**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add an edge split modifier and set the angle to max (180). Does that give the shape you want?

Comment: you have a very twisted ngon:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GudMa.png Nogons do not subdivide well. Also try to avoid non planar geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the changed shaped is the **Merge** option.

The vertices of the blade are directly on the merge plane XY but they are connect to vertices on the handle, which don't get merged. This result in some different connections.

A solution could be to turn off the merge option on the mirror modifier.

[image]

---

## BUT...

... your topology is horrible. Here are some steps to fix it.

1. Grab the faces of the blade and move them down, of the XY merge plane. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
   [image]
2. Don't use triangles, remove the upper edge of the triangle at the transition. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> > <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
   [image]
   Create a new vertice by extruding. <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> > [drag] > <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>
3. Turn on the mirror modifier again (not subsurf though), select the edges along the ridge and extrude them upwards so the mirrored parts are joined.
   [image]
4. Your topology should be a clear flow of quads. If you wish you can counteract the smoothing of the subsurf by marking certain edges as sharp. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select them and mark sharp <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.
   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

[image]

Merge those two vertices and problem solved:

[image]